# Invalid operation the connection is closed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

[image]

this error shows up while creating a new record,  ? As far as i think, it's kind of memory leakage problem, i did open connection and forgot to close it , transaction manager has locked it i suppose, but how to fix it :-? I have tried different settings but nothing worked. This type of errors makes my work slow

Comment: Was this resolved? How?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use activity manager to solve this problem 
using activity manager close the open connection for the user
```